# Problem getting only one color for every pallet type id

Tags: anylogic

I have a database with my different pallet types which have an ID. Now I would like to assign to every ID a color. So for example at 10 am 54 pallets with the id 6 (blue) should be insert into my source block. So I filled the rectangular color with the code getStandardColor. Problem is that instead of one color per type I get different colors (screenshot) which were insert into my source block. So how can I get one color for one type (id)?
Thank you very much! It's very important for me to get the different colors (one color for one id) for the ids.

[pallets_2dsimulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKcep.png)

[pallettype_2D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j2kv.png)

[dbase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvyKr.png)

[dbase_pallet_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aPPZ.png)

[source_block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhXZV.png)

Comment: if you get different colors, it means that you have different IDs... you are just not realizing that... getStandardColor(id) gives you one color per id, so you are doing something else wrong that is not stated in your question

Comment: I attached a lot of screenshots, and there is nothing to find? :/

Comment: if you want me to debug your model, then send your model, otherwise, you have my answer already.. you pallet ids are probably different than what you think... i can't say more

Comment: oh.. by the way, now you added a new database for pallets id, when i helped you I used the arrivals ids... so that seems to be wrong now... I think you really need major help in terms of your whole model design, and you won't get a solution solution asking individual questions... This is not a problem about colors, this is a problem about your model being probably full of errors of different types...

Comment: thank you. I will test it for the next days to solve it by myself. How could I contact you when I can‘t solve it?

Comment: check my profile.. it has my contact info